# A float is changing from 0.5 to 0.48 on update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

When my user is updating the database, through software which should just run an update statement, it will change the value from a 0.5 to a 0.48 seemingly at random. I changed some code around so that they would simply select what they needed from a very specific list and I would pass that to the database in a stored procedure rather than trusting the software to do the right thing but it has just occurred again.

Would this be a bug in the software or is there something I'm missing about the float datatype? I know it's not exact but if you put in a '0.50', change that from a varchar to a float in a cast statement and there isn't a trigger changing the value how could it possibly change to a 0.48 and only sometimes? I'm at an absolute loss.

Please have mercy if it's something obvious, I am completely self-taught and can't find anything to explain.

Edit

I apologize for not giving the code of the stored procedure. It felt like an abstract problem. Here is the stored proceedure.

```sql
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [cd].[sp_newendtime_clienttime]    Script Date: 10/11/2022 9:22:16 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [cd].[sp_newendtime_clienttime] (
    @activworkid_c varchar(18),
    @staffandclienttime_vc varchar(4),
    @newendtime_vc varchar(5)
   )

as 

BEGIN

    IF @newendtime_vc = '  :  ' OR @newendtime_vc IS NULL OR @newendtime_vc = '' OR @newendtime_vc = ' '
    BEGIN
    UPDATE ar.activwork
    SET
        staffduration_n = CAST(@staffandclienttime_vc AS FLOAT),
        clientduration_n = CAST(@staffandclienttime_vc AS FLOAT)
    WHERE activwork.uniqueid_c = @activworkid_c
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
    UPDATE ar.activwork
    SET
        component2_c = @newendtime_vc,
        staffduration_n = CAST(@staffandclienttime_vc AS FLOAT),
        clientduration_n = CAST(@staffandclienttime_vc AS FLOAT)
    WHERE activwork.uniqueid_c = @activworkid_c
    END

END
```

Comment: I would not be surprised if the "bug" is the fact you are using a `float`.

Comment: so it *is* something to do with the float data type? The software isn't mine obviously and was built quite a long time ago by a company I don't have much faith in but I'm not allowed to change the table because then they won't help us.

Comment: In truth, however, without an [mre] we can do little more than guess, and [so] isn't a site for us *guessing* what the problem and solution is; it's a site for specific questions with specific answers.

Comment: A 4% difference is much, much too big of a variance to blame on the nature of floating point numbers.

Comment: We can't run that procedure on it's own; we don't have a copy of your table's DDL, any sample data, nor the parameter(s) you are passing. This is why we need a full [mre] that demonstrates the undesired behaviour.

Comment: add database trigger which will log all changes to this column into separate table and try to detect when it happens

Comment: I don't disagree, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft . I wouldn't be surprised if it's a contributing factor, but we're certainly missing other factors. The use of a `varchar` parameter for a numerical value is probably another (contributing factor).

Comment: @Larnu what other information would be useful? I'll be happy to add. Unfortunately, I have to use the Varchar as that's how the software we're working through works.

Comment: As I said, create a [mre]; then we can we can also do our own test to see when and where the problem is happening.

Comment: @Larnu In the question itself, it states that it happens at random. It's not something I can guarantee reproduces every time in that code but that's the code that does the updating so that's what seems to be the minimum. What else can I give you? Would the table creation script be helpful? That link you keep sending is not helpful as this is something that I can't reproduce because it's very much random. I'm going to try the log suggestion to hopefully see if I can find a link.

Comment: Yes, as I stated, we don't have the table's DDL not any sample data that replicates the issue. We *need* replication here. If you are using application code to call the procedure then we are likely going to need that too. Basically you need to include all the relevant code you have already debugged, along with sample data & parameters, so that we can replicate the behaviour and debug it.

Comment: I can't access the application code, just the table, 2 out of 3 of its triggers, the trigger that calls the stored procedure, and the stored procedure itself. Would that be enough or would it be better to just delete this since I can't give you everything?